# $\frac{\lfloor x \rfloor}{x} \to 1$ as $x \to \infty$?

Tags: limits, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Could anyone be able to explain to me why $\frac{\lfloor x \rfloor}{x} \to 1$ as $x \to \infty$?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For every $x \ge 0$, we have $x-1 < \lfloor x \rfloor \le x$, thus
$$
\frac{x-1}x < \frac{\lfloor x \rfloor}x \le \frac xx = 1. 
$$
By the sandwich theorem, you have your result.

Comment: The first inequality  is strict.

Comment: @Bernard : Yes. But if it's strict, it implies that it is also not-strict. The converse is false in general. Since I didn't need the strict inequality and I was too tired to think about which of the two was strict again, I just didn't care. ;)

Comment: In my opinion,it would be more pedagogical to keep it strict: it gives one more opportunity to insist on the fact  that strict inequality  are not preserved on passing to the limit.

Comment: @Bernard : I hope you are happy now.

Comment: No man will ever be as happy as I am :-J

Answer (score 3):

Because,
if $x > 0$,
$x = \lfloor x \rfloor
+\{ x \}
$
(integer part plus fractional part).

Therefore
$\dfrac{\lfloor x \rfloor}{x}-1
=\dfrac{\lfloor x \rfloor-x}{x}
=\dfrac{-\{ x \}}{x}
\to 0
$
as
$x \to \infty$
since
$0 \le \{ x \} < 1$.

Answer (score 2):

Fill in details:

Putting $\;x-\lfloor x\rfloor=\{x\}=\;$ the fractional part of $\;x\;$ , one gets:

$$\frac{\lfloor x\rfloor}x=\frac{x-\{x\}}x=1-\frac{\{x\}}x\xrightarrow[x\to\infty]{}1$$

Answer (score 1):

Think of  $x$ as   some amount of money which needs dollars and cents to express something like 355 dollars and 78 cents.
If we are not to mention cents then we can say this amount is \$355.78

When the amount gets very high like  millions and billions,  its value is nearly as good if we omit the cents and mention only whole dollars. This is what the floor  function does. What is the percentage loss when you are literally short-changed , say instead of getting a payment of \$300258 plus 93 cents you were given just \$300258.

Mathematical symbolism is a way of expressing precisely some statements. It helps understanding to go back to the less precise statement in words that it is being symbolized..